# How long the user can wait for help (chat)

Tags: time, chat

I create a chat (support) for application.

Are there any research about how long the user can wait for help? I want to ensure that after a specific time the user will be connected with the consultant.

Of course, the longer the better for the consultant.

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful to analyze your use case in more detail. Meaning - it is critical to understand why you need the chat in first place?

Are you trying to driver conversions, transactions, traffic, etc?

I see there are two approaches here-

1. Time - show the chat after XX seconds/minutes of inactivity or normal browsing
   You should test and try different time intervals and,hopefully, determine what is the best time to use. However, it is very critical to target the right users here. It might be highly detrimental to target users that are already on the way to achieving the desired goal (conversion, transaction, etc)
2. Trigger Based - show the chat when the user does/does not do a certain action in your conversion funnel. For ex: in one of my older organizations, I saw an increasing trend of users who were on the last step of the cart i.e. making the payment, but kept failing. I also was able to identify that most of these users were serious about transacting with us; because after a failure, they would take the pain of trying to complete the transaction again at least 2 more times. 
   This data was enough for me to know that I am losing the best possible customers due to whatever unknown reasons.
   As a result I implemented an auto chat pop-up, that would pop-up on the third failed attempt. 
   The chat was not the root cause of the above problem, but it was a step to uncover what the root cause could be.